# pc is not asking debugging authorization permission in android

Tags: android, windows, permissions, xiaomi, usb-debugging

my PC model is dell inspiron n4110 running on windows 8.1 pro and my android is xiaomi redmi 4 running on android 7.0 . as i turned on settings related to debugging like developer options>usb debugging and then connected to my pc , still it doesn't ask for usb debugging permission when connected through usb cable

Comment: Make sure to check `Control Panel->Device Manager` and install any missing drivers for your phone.

Comment: @Siju thank you for answering . as i checked , there is an error in adb interface under the device manager. can you please check me the appropriate driver for my model and help me by sending the link through telegram, or whatsapp?

Answer (score 0):

I am not on `Windows` machine right now so my answer might be a little vague.

These are the steps you can follow to recognise any device (`Xiaomi`, `Samsung` etc.) without installing specific drivers for each.

1. Make sure you have `Android SDK` installed and the `Google USB driver` is installed using `SDK Manager` -> `SDK Tools`.
2. Go to `Control Panel -> Device Manager` and right click on `ADB interface` and choose `Update drivers`.
3. Select `Browse from computer` and then select your `SDK directory`-> `extras`->`google`
4. After choosing the folder, click on `Next` and you should be able to see either `ADB` or `Google USB` in the next screen. You can select that and let the drivers install.
5. If `Step 4` didn't work, you can choose `Let me choose from installed..` after selecting the `SDK` folder
6. Reconnect your device and it should show the `Allow USB debugging` dialog.

Comment: thanks for replying. i am new in this field , so now only i started learning. first , i installed android studio and tried to run , but unfortunately , i had an error , shown as "api-ms-win-crt-stdio-|1-1-0.dll"  so . can you please guide me to what to do next.

Comment: if you don't mind , can you please help me directly ? if you can , please reach me out  here https://www.instagram.com/does.n.t/